# Android Layout: Center RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, alignment

I'm trying to center Radiobuttons in a Radiogroup. I had a solution with

```
<RadioGroup [...]>
    <RelativeLayout [...]>
        <RadioButton [...]/>
    </RelativLaoyout>
    <RelativeLayout [...]>
        <RadioButton [...]/>
    </RelativLaoyout>
    <RelativeLayout [...]>
        <RadioButton [...]/>
    </RelativLaoyout>
</RadioGroup>
```

But if I do this, the RadioButtons can all be checked at same time, which I want to prevent with Radiogroup to get single selection.
To get the logic with single selection automatically, the RadioButtons have to be direct child of RadioGroup without being wrapped in a layout.

Here's my current code:

```
 <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="4">

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
          android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And the result:
[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xde8E.png)

Comment: `RadioGroup` does not support nesting it's `RadioButton` children in an intermediate view group. You cannot have structure as mentioned in the desired example working out of the box **without additional work**. I had the same case and basically connected `View.OnClickListener` to each of the `RadioButton`s. I was using Kotlin + [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) - it made things 10 times simpler. If you are interested I can post an example.

Comment: ok, the solution with onClickListener doesn't work properly, that's why I wanted to use the native solution. Would be nice, if you post a solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1: enable data binding

First of all, you have to enable data binding.

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
}
```

Two ways how you can get familiar with data binding:

- [codelab based on data binding](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#0) in case you want an hour-long project to get into data binding;
- [just documentation with examples](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start).

#### Step 2: define enum and click listener

*I suggest you are using Java so the code will be in Java. It can be automatically converted to Kotlin in Android Studio IDE in case you need it.*

We need to define an `enum` class with 4 values. Let it be:

```
public enum Value {
    FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH;
}
```

Click listener won't actually be of type `View.OnClickListener`. It will be called by the `View.OnClickListener` using data binding. Pretty simple and you will see it on step 3.

```
interface OnValueSelectListener {
    public void onValueSelected(Value value);
}
```

#### Step 3: implement a layout using data binding

I guess at this step you are already familiar with data binding and how to work with it. In this layout, we will define.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <!-- Data declaration -->
    <data>

        <import type="com.example.app.Value" />
        <!-- Architecture component whose updates are rendered live as soon as it changed -->
        <!-- Nothing to do special. All is done by the data binding library -->
        <variable
            name="observableSelectedValue"
            type="androidx.databinding.ObservableField" />

        <variable
            name="onValueSelectListener"
            type="com.example.app.OnValueSelectListener" />
    </data>

    <!--  Layout declaration -->
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="@{observableSelectedValue == Value.FIRST}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{() -> onValueSelectListener.onValueSelected(Value.FIRST)}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="@{observableSelectedValue == Value.SECOND}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{() -> onValueSelectListener.onValueSelected(Value.SECOND)}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="@{observableSelectedValue == Value.THIRD}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{() -> onValueSelectListener.onValueSelected(Value.THIRD)}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="@{observableSelectedValue == Value.FOURTH}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{() -> onValueSelectListener.onValueSelected(Value.FOURTH)}" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</layout>
```

#### Step 4: update Activity/Fragment

With the layout updated rebuild the project and apply the next changes to the creation of layout in your Activity or Fragment:

*Updates for Activity*

```
private ObservableField<Value> observableSelectedValue = new ObservableField<>(Value.FIRST);
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    YourLayoutNameBinding viewBinding = YourLayoutNameBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), null, false);
    setContentView(viewBinding.getRoot());
    
    viewBinding.setObservableSelectedValue(observableSelectedValue);
    viewBinding.setOnValueSelectListener(new OnValueSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Value value) {
            observableSelectedValue.set(value);
        }
    });
}
```

*Updates for Fragment*

```
private ObservableField<Value> observableSelectedValue = new ObservableField<>(Value.FIRST);
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    YourLayoutNameBinding viewBinding = YourLayoutNameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    viewBinding.setObservableSelectedValue(observableSelectedValue);
    viewBinding.setOnValueSelectListener(new OnValueSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Value value) {
            observableSelectedValue.set(value);
        }
    });
    return viewBinding.getRoot();
}
```

#### Step 5: run & test

It must work now. To get the currently selected value you need to call `observableSelectedValue.get()`.